# How common is tar support for unpacking tars with long names (100+ characters)?

Tags: tar, posix

Today I encountered an issue where I couldn't tar a file with Java using Commons-Compress on Windows because one of the file names was longer than 100 characters. I was looking for solutions and found:

According to https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-compress/tar.html

> There are several different dialects of the TAR format, maybe even different TAR formats. The tar package contains special cases in order to read many of the existing dialects and will by default try to create archives in the original format (often called "ustar"). This original format didn't support file names longer than 100 characters or bigger than 8 GiB and the tar package will by default fail if you try to write an entry that goes beyond those limits. "ustar" is the common denominator of all the existing tar dialects and is understood by most of the existing tools.
>
> LONGFILE_POSIX: use a PAX extended header as defined by POSIX 1003.1. Most modern tar implementations are able to extract such archives. since Commons Compress 1.4

The documentation mentions "most modern tar implementations". Which commonly used tar implementations do not support filenames longer than 100 characters through a PAX header? Are the tar implementations that do not support PAX extended headers still in common use? I still need to be able to open .tar.gz files created with Commons-Compress on Windows using common tar implementations on Linux and Unix.

Comment: Please give a list of `tar` implementations you like to get information for

Answer (score 0):

I've just successfully packed and unpacked a tar archive containing:

```bsh
touch $(for i in {1..222}; do echo -n a; done)

file test.tar 
test.tar: POSIX tar archive (GNU)
```

So there should be no issues in Linux, at least Fedora 32. 7z/WinRAR both open the same archive and extract the file successfully.

As for Commons-Compress extension/format I've no idea, as http://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual doesn't have anything of the kind.

Maybe you could share such an archive, so that it could be tested?